# Get the list of system datatypes

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a class with many properties with different types including some custom class types. Now I want to find those properties which are not of system types like :

- `System.Int32`
- `System.Boolean`
- `System.String`
- `System.Decimal`
- and so on

Currently I am doing things like this way :

```
Dim objProperties As PropertyInfo() = GetType(MyClassType).GetProperties()

For Each objPropertyInfo As PropertyInfo In objProperties
    If Not objPropertyInfo.PropertyType() Is GetType(Int32) And Not objPropertyInfo.PropertyType() Is GetType(String) Then
        'other code
    End If
Next
```

If I can get the desired list, then the `If` condition could be more simple like :

```
If Not systemTypeList.Contains(objPropertyInfo.Name) Then
```

Comment: `objPropertyInfo.PropertyType().Namespace <> "System"`? What do you intend to do differently if it's not a "System" type?

Comment: That's a long story! In short, I just need the properties that are not of System type.

Comment: You probably care if the type is [`IConvertible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @D Stanley for the hint of a solution. I am wrapping up the solution.

```
Dim strProperties As New List(Of String)
Dim objProperties As PropertyInfo() = GetType(InvoiceType).GetProperties()

strProperties = objProperties.Where(Function(p) p.PropertyType.Namespace <> "System").Select(Function(p) p.Name).ToList()
```

Here I am generating the list of the properties which are not of any system types like `String, Decimal etc` So now, I can write the `If` condition easily like :

```
If strProperties.Contains(objPropertyInfo.Name) Then
```